# ColdFusion: turn array into struct name

Tags: arrays, data-structures, coldfusion, struct

The form input name of:

```
user[subscriptions][1,28][_delete]
```

Essentially turns into a struct like this:

User

-Subscriptions

--1,28

---_delete

But how can you manually create a struct like this?

You can't do:

```
<cfset user.subscriptions.1,28._delete = 1>
```

CF doesn't like the comma in the struct name. But I need to be able to create the struct like this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<cfset user[ 'subscriptions' ][ '1,28' ][ '_delete' ] = 1 />`

Array notation lets you get away with all kinds of illegal variable names :)

Comment: DOH! ... I neglected to use quotes ... :)